# Help me recover my password

Tags: password-recovery

I installed Ubuntu and immediately forgot the simple password.

Is there a straightforward way to recover it?

Comment: If it is a new install without any important data on it, the easiest way would just to install again.  This time writing down the password, before you install Ubuntu.  Copy password when Ubuntu asks for it.